# Получить элементы коллекции, где свойство B имеет максимум в пределах окна по свойству A

Tags: c#, linq

Как преобразовать набор

```
A = 1; B = 7;
A = 1; B = 3;
A = 1; B = 1;
A = 2; B = 1;
A = 2; B = 2;
A = 3; B = 4;
```

к набору

```
A = 1; B = 7;
A = 2; B = 2;
A = 3; B = 4;
```

с помощью LINQ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В группах по A выбираем максимум по B

```
myData.GroupBy(x => x.A).Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(z=>z.B).First());
```

Answer (score 2):

Вариант без сортировки c MoreLinq

```
list.GroupBy(x => x.A).Select(x => x.MaxBy(y => y.B).First());
```